# php mysql android ошибка при отправке данных в андроиде 5 и 6

Tags: php, android, mysql

В андроид 7 все работает четко...

```
       <pre>


     package tj.bitmaster.navinservices;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.BufferedWriter;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.io.OutputStream;
        import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
        import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
        import java.net.MalformedURLException;
        import java.net.URL;
        import java.net.URLEncoder;

        import static com.google.android.gms.internal.zzahn.runOnUiThread;

        public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        AlertDialog alertDialog;
        String bank;
        Context context;
        int count = 0;
        String login_status;
        String password;
        String phone_number;
        String user_status;
        String username;

        BackgroundWorker(Context ctx) {
            this.context = ctx;
        }



        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String insert_url = "http:/novation.tj/services/data.php";
            if (!isOnline()) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(((Activity)context), "Нет соединения с интернетом!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
            } else {


                if (strings[0].equals("insert")) {
                    try {
                        String name = strings[1];
                        String email = strings[2];
                        String problems = strings[3];
                        String problem = strings[4];
                        String photourl = strings[5];
                        String phone = strings[6];
                        String model_NO = strings[7];
                        String date = strings[8];
                        String fio = strings[9];
                        String organization = strings[10];
                        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(insert_url).openConnection();
                        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                        OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                        bufferedWriter.write(URLEncoder.encode("model", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "&"
                                + URLEncoder.encode("model_data", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8") + "&"
                                + URLEncoder.encode("problems", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(problems, "UTF-8") + "&"
                                + URLEncoder.encode("problem", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(problem, "UTF-8") + "&"
                                + URLEncoder.encode(PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID, "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(phone, "UTF-8") + "&"
                                + URLEncoder.encode("photourl", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(photourl, "UTF-8") + "&"
                                + URLEncoder.encode("model_NO", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(model_NO, "UTF-8") + "&"
                                + URLEncoder.encode("date", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(date, "UTF-8") + "&"
                                + URLEncoder.encode("fio", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(fio, "UTF-8") + "&"
                                + URLEncoder.encode("organization", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(organization, "UTF-8") + "&");
                        bufferedWriter.flush();
                        bufferedWriter.close();
                        outputStream.close();
                        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                        String result = "";
                        String str = "";
                        while (true) {
                            str = bufferedReader.readLine();
                            if (str != null) {
                                result = result + str;
                            } else {
                                bufferedReader.close();
                                inputStream.close();
                                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                                return result;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e2) {
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }


        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.alertDialog = new Builder(this.context).create();
            this.alertDialog.setTitle("Статус заявки");
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null) {
                if (result.equals("INSERT Succesful")) {
                    this.alertDialog.setMessage("Заявка отправлена");
                } else if (result.equals("Error")) {
                    this.alertDialog.setMessage("Ошибка при отправки заявки!!!");
                } else {
                    this.alertDialog.setMessage(result);
                }

            }else {
                result = "ошибка при отправке";
            }
            this.login_status = result;
            this.alertDialog.show();
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
        protected boolean isOnline() {
            String cs = Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE;
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) ((Activity)context).getSystemService(cs);
            if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null) {
                return false;
            } else { return true; }
        } 

</pre>
```

Код PHP:

```
<pre>

    require "conn.php";
    $name = $_POST["model"];
    $email = $_POST["model_data"];
    $problems = $_POST["problems"];
    $problem = $_POST["problem"];
    $photourl = $_POST["photourl"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $model_NO = $_POST["model_NO"];
    $date = $_POST["date"];
    $fio = $_POST["fio"];
    $organization = $_POST["organization"];
    $mail = "2";

    $mysql_qry = "insert into a_ns_request (model, model_data, problems, problem, photo_url,phone,model_NO,date,name,organization,email_status) values('$name','$email','$problems','$problem','$photourl','$phone','$model_NO','$date','$fio','$organization',$mail)";
    if($conn->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE){
        echo "INSERT Succesful";
    }else{

      echo "Error";
    }
    $conn->close();

</pre>
```

Код ошибки:

```
<pre>

     W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: 
        http:/novation.tj/services/data.php
        W/System.err:     at 
        com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:352)
        W/System.err:     at 
        com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:295)
        W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
        W/System.err:     at 
     com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
    W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:208)
    W/System.err:     at tj.bitmaster.navinservices.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:71)
    W/System.err:     at tj.bitmaster.navinservices.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:26)
     </pre>
```

Comment: А на устройствах 5 и 6 с сетью всё в порядке?

Comment: Да, вот коды для доступа сети:


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: У Вас слэш в адресе пропущен `http://novation.tj/services/data.php` - 7-ой Андроид наверное сам исправляет.